# Check current foreground application in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have one application that runs in the background, which knows when any of the built-in applications (messaging, contacts, etc) is running.This apps work fine in below android 6.

```
try {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) aContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        PackageManager packageManager = aContext.getPackageManager();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
            Log.e("VERSION", "+++++++++++++++" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            String currentProcName = "";
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : am.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
                currentProcName = processInfo.processName;
                ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(processInfo.processName, 0);
                String title = (String) ((applicationInfo != null) ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "???");
                Log.e("show app", "+++++++++++++++" + currentProcName + "---- applicationInfo  " + applicationInfo.uid + "app name  " + title);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("VERSION", "===============================" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am
                    .getRunningTasks(1);
            for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : alltasks) {
                String CurrentString = aTask.topActivity.flattenToShortString();
                String[] separated = CurrentString.split("/");
                Log.e("show app", "+++++++++++++++" + "packageName  " + separated[0]);
                ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(separated[0], 0);
                final String title = (String) ((applicationInfo != null) ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo) : "???");
                Log.e("show app", "+++++++++++++++" + "---- applicationInfo  " + applicationInfo.uid + "app name  " + title);
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("show", "Throwable caught: " + t.getMessage(), t);
    }
```

How to get information of foreground application in android 6?

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: `GET_TASKS` Deprecated .

Comment: did you find any solution for the problem @anil?